# ReactJs Menu Links Stacking Main Section Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, history

I have a ReactJS Web App using BrowserRouter with react-router-dom.  There is a base component that has a sidebar and a section that includes props.children.  If I put the url for a valid route in the address bar, it loads fine, but it has to load the whole app including the header and sidebar.  But, if I click a link on the sidebar, it only loads the section with the new page.  The problem is that it also includes the previous page below the new page.  So, for some reason when the link on the sidebar menu is pressed, the children.props are just adding the new component to the existing on.

Heres app.js:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {authenticated: false};
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, prevContext) {
    if (this.props.state.sessionState.appUser && !this.state.authenticated) {
        this.setState({authenticated: true});
    }
}

render() {

// specify base href from env varible 'WP_BASE_HREF'
// use only if application isn't served from the root
// for development it is forced to root only
/* global WP_BASE_HREF */
const basename = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : (WP_BASE_HREF || '/');


        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename={basename}>
                <Routes/>
            </BrowserRouter>);
```

}

}

here is the Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import Base from './components/Layout/Base';
import BasePage from './components/Layout/BasePage';
// import BaseHorizontal from './components/Layout/BaseHorizontal';

import CompanyList from './components/Company/CompanyList'
import CompanyDetail from './components/Company/CompanyDetail'
import CompanyCreate from './components/Company/CompanyCreate'
import MyAccount from './components/Users/MyAccount'
import UserList from './components/Users/UserList'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';

import ToolList from './components/Tools/ToolList';
import ToolCreate from './components/Tools/ToolCreate';

import Widgets from './components/Widgets/Widgets';

import Buttons from './components/Elements/Buttons';
import Notifications from './components/Elements/Notifications';
import SweetAlert from './components/Elements/SweetAlert';
import BsCarousel from './components/Elements/Carousel';
import Spinner from './components/Elements/Spinner';
import Animation from './components/Elements/Animation';
import DropdownAnimation from './components/Elements/DropdownAnimation';
import Nestable from './components/Elements/Nestable';
import Sortable from './components/Elements/Sortable';
import Cards from './components/Elements/Cards';
import Grid from './components/Elements/Grid';
import GridMasonry from './components/Elements/GridMasonry';
import Typography from './components/Elements/Typography';
import FontIcons from './components/Elements/FontIcons';
import WeatherIcons from './components/Elements/WeatherIcons';
import Colors from './components/Elements/Colors';

import ChartFlot from './components/Charts/ChartFlot';
import ChartRadial from './components/Charts/ChartRadial';
import ChartChartJS from './components/Charts/ChartChartJS';
import ChartMorris from './components/Charts/ChartMorris';
import ChartChartist from './components/Charts/ChartChartist';

import MapsGoogle from './components/Maps/MapsGoogle';
import MapsVector from './components/Maps/MapsVector';

import TableStandard from './components/Tables/TableStandard';
import TableExtended from './components/Tables/TableExtended';
import Datatable from './components/Tables/DatatableView';
import DataGrid from './components/Tables/DataGrid';

import FormStandard from './components/Forms/FormStandard';
import FormExtended from './components/Forms/FormExtended';
import FormValidation from './components/Forms/FormValidation';
import FormWizard from './components/Forms/FormWizard';
import FormUpload from './components/Forms/FormUpload';
import FormCropper from './components/Forms/FormCropper';

import Login from './components/Pages/Login';
import Register from './components/Pages/Register';
import Recover from './components/Pages/Recover';
import Lock from './components/Pages/Lock';
import NotFound from './components/Pages/NotFound';
import Error500 from './components/Pages/Error500';
import Maintenance from './components/Pages/Maintenance';

import Mailbox from './components/Extras/Mailbox';
import Timeline from './components/Extras/Timeline';
import Calendar from './components/Extras/Calendar';
import Invoice from './components/Extras/Invoice';
import Search from './components/Extras/Search';
import Todo from './components/Extras/Todo';
import Profile from './components/Extras/Profile';
import BugTracker from './components/Extras/BugTracker';
import ContactDetails from './components/Extras/ContactDetails';
import Contacts from './components/Extras/Contacts';
import Faq from './components/Extras/Faq';
import FileManager from './components/Extras/FileManager';
import Followers from './components/Extras/Followers';
import HelpCenter from './components/Extras/HelpCenter';
import Plans from './components/Extras/Plans';
import ProjectDetails from './components/Extras/ProjectDetails';
import Projects from './components/Extras/Projects';
import Settings from './components/Extras/Settings';
import SocialBoard from './components/Extras/SocialBoard';
import TeamViewer from './components/Extras/TeamViewer';
import VoteLinks from './components/Extras/VoteLinks';

import EcommerceOrder from './components/Ecommerce/EcommerceOrders';
import EcommerceOrderView from './components/Ecommerce/EcommerceOrderView';
import EcommerceProduct from './components/Ecommerce/EcommerceProducts';
import EcommerceProductView from './components/Ecommerce/EcommerceProductView';
import EcommerceCheckout from './components/Ecommerce/EcommerceCheckout';

import BlogList from './components/Blog/BlogList';
import BlogPost from './components/Blog/BlogPost';
import BlogArticle from './components/Blog/BlogArticles';
import BlogArticleView from './components/Blog/BlogArticleView';

import ForumCategories from './components/Forum/ForumCategories';
import ForumTopic from './components/Forum/ForumTopics';
import ForumDiscussion from './components/Forum/ForumDiscussion';
import q from './components/AdminTools/querytools';


// List of routes that uses the page layout
// listed here to Switch between layouts
// depending on the current pathname
const listofPages = [
    '/login',
    '/register',
    '/recover',
    '/lock',
    '/notfound',
    '/error500',
    '/maintenance'
];

const Routes = ({ location }) => {
    const currentKey = location.pathname.split('/')[1] || '/';
    const timeout = { enter: 500, exit: 500 };

    // Animations supported
    //      'rag-fadeIn'
    //      'rag-fadeInUp'
    //      'rag-fadeInDown'
    //      'rag-fadeInRight'
    //      'rag-fadeInLeft'
    //      'rag-fadeInUpBig'
    //      'rag-fadeInDownBig'
    //      'rag-fadeInRightBig'
    //      'rag-fadeInLeftBig'
    //      'rag-zoomBackDown'
    const animationName = 'rag-fadeIn'

    if(listofPages.indexOf(location.pathname) > -1) {
        return (
            // Page Layout component wrapper
            <BasePage>
                <Switch location={location}>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
                    <Route path="/recover" component={Recover}/>
                    <Route path="/lock" component={Lock}/>
                    <Route path="/notfound" component={NotFound}/>
                    <Route path="/error500" component={Error500}/>
                    <Route path="/maintenance" component={Maintenance}/>
                </Switch>
            </BasePage>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            // Layout component wrapper
            // Use <BaseHorizontal> to change layout
            <Base>
              <TransitionGroup>
                <CSSTransition key={currentKey} timeout={timeout} classNames={animationName} exit={false}>
                    <div>
                        <Switch location={location}>


                            {/*My Company*/}
                            <Route path="/companyList" component={CompanyList}/>
                            <Route path="/companyDetail" component={CompanyDetail}/>
                            <Route path="/companyCreate" component={CompanyCreate}/>

                            {/* User */}
                            <Route path="/users" component={UserList}/>
                            <Route path="/myAccount" component={MyAccount}/>


                            {/*Dashboard*/}
                            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>

                            {/* Tools  */}
                            <Route path="/toolList" component={ToolList}/>
                            <Route path="/toolCreate" component={ToolCreate}/>

                            {/*Widgets*/}
                            <Route path="/widgets" component={Widgets}/>

                            {/*Elements*/}
                            <Route path="/buttons" component={Buttons}/>
                            <Route path="/notifications" component={Notifications}/>
                            <Route path="/sweetalert" component={SweetAlert}/>
                            <Route path="/carousel" component={BsCarousel}/>
                            <Route path="/spinners" component={Spinner}/>
                            <Route path="/animations" component={Animation}/>
                            <Route path="/dropdown" component={DropdownAnimation}/>
                            <Route path="/nestable" component={Nestable}/>
                            <Route path="/sortable" component={Sortable}/>
                            <Route path="/cards" component={Cards}/>
                            <Route path="/grid" component={Grid}/>
                            <Route path="/grid-masonry" component={GridMasonry}/>
                            <Route path="/typography" component={Typography}/>
                            <Route path="/icons-font" component={FontIcons}/>
                            <Route path="/icons-weather" component={WeatherIcons}/>
                            <Route path="/colors" component={Colors}/>

                            {/*Forms*/}
                            <Route path="/form-standard" component={FormStandard}/>
                            <Route path="/form-extended" component={FormExtended}/>
                            <Route path="/form-validation" component={FormValidation}/>
                            <Route path="/form-wizard" component={FormWizard}/>
                            <Route path="/form-upload" component={FormUpload}/>
                            <Route path="/form-cropper" component={FormCropper}/>

                            {/*Charts*/}
                            <Route path="/chart-flot" component={ChartFlot}/>
                            <Route path="/chart-radial" component={ChartRadial}/>
                            <Route path="/chart-chartjs" component={ChartChartJS}/>
                            <Route path="/chart-morris" component={ChartMorris}/>
                            <Route path="/chart-chartist" component={ChartChartist}/>

                            {/*Table*/}
                            <Route path="/table-standard" component={TableStandard}/>
                            <Route path="/table-extended" component={TableExtended}/>
                            <Route path="/table-datatable" component={Datatable}/>
                            <Route path="/table-datagrid" component={DataGrid}/>

                            {/*Maps*/}
                            <Route path="/map-google" component={MapsGoogle}/>
                            <Route path="/map-vector" component={MapsVector}/>

                            {/*Extras*/}
                            <Route path="/mailbox" component={Mailbox}/>
                            <Route path="/timeline" component={Timeline}/>
                            <Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar}/>
                            <Route path="/invoice" component={Invoice}/>
                            <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
                            <Route path="/todo" component={Todo}/>
                            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
                            <Route path="/ecommerce-orders" component={EcommerceOrder}/>
                            <Route path="/ecommerce-order-view" component={EcommerceOrderView}/>
                            <Route path="/ecommerce-products" component={EcommerceProduct}/>
                            <Route path="/ecommerce-product-view" component={EcommerceProductView}/>
                            <Route path="/ecommerce-checkout" component={EcommerceCheckout}/>
                            <Route path="/blog-list" component={BlogList}/>
                            <Route path="/blog-post" component={BlogPost}/>
                            <Route path="/blog-articles" component={BlogArticle}/>
                            <Route path="/blog-article-view" component={BlogArticleView}/>
                            <Route path="/forum-categories" component={ForumCategories}/>
                            <Route path="/forum-topics" component={ForumTopic}/>
                            <Route path="/forum-discussion" component={ForumDiscussion}/>
                            <Route path="/bug-tracker" component={BugTracker}/>
                            <Route path="/contact-details" component={ContactDetails}/>
                            <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
                            <Route path="/faq" component={Faq}/>
                            <Route path="/file-manager" component={FileManager}/>
                            <Route path="/followers" component={Followers}/>
                            <Route path="/help-center" component={HelpCenter}/>
                            <Route path="/plans" component={Plans}/>
                            <Route path="/project-details" component={ProjectDetails}/>
                            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
                            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                            <Route path="/social-board" component={SocialBoard}/>
                            <Route path="/team-viewer" component={TeamViewer}/>
                            <Route path="/vote-links" component={VoteLinks}/>
                            <Route path="/q" component={q}/>


                            <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </CSSTransition>
              </TransitionGroup>
            </Base>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

Here is the base.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './Header'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Offsidebar from './Offsidebar'
import Footer from './Footer'

const Base = props => (
    <div className="wrapper">
        <Header />

        <Sidebar />

        <Offsidebar />

        <section className="section-container">
            { props.children }
        </section>

        <Footer />
    </div>
)

export default Base;
```

and here is the sidebar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { translate, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Collapse, Badge } from 'reactstrap';

import SidebarRun from './Sidebar.run';
import SidebarUserBlock from './SidebarUserBlock';

import MenuData from '../../Menu.js';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {compose} from "recompose";

/** Component to display headings on sidebar */
const SidebarItemHeader = ({item}) => (
    <li className="nav-heading">
        <span><Trans i18nKey={item.translate}>{item.heading}</Trans></span>
    </li>
)

/** Normal items for the sidebar */
const SidebarItem = ({item, isActive}) => (
    <li className={ isActive ? 'active' : '' }>
        <Link to={item.path} title={item.name}>
            {item.label && <Badge tag="div" className="pull-right" color={item.label.color}>{item.label.value}</Badge>}
            {item.icon && <em className={item.icon}></em>}
            <span><Trans i18nKey={item.translate}>{item.name}</Trans></span>
        </Link>
    </li>
)

/** Build a sub menu with items inside and attach collapse behavior */
const SidebarSubItem = ({item, isActive, handler, children, isOpen}) => (
    <li className={ isActive ? 'active' : '' }>
        <div className="nav-item" onClick={ handler }>
            {item.label && <Badge tag="div" className="pull-right" color={item.label.color}>{item.label.value}</Badge>}
            {item.icon && <em className={item.icon}></em>}
            <span><Trans i18nKey={item.translate}>{item.name}</Trans></span>
        </div>
        <Collapse isOpen={ isOpen }>
            <ul id={item.path} className="sidebar-nav sidebar-subnav">
                { children }
            </ul>
        </Collapse>
    </li>
)

/** Component used to display a header on menu when using collapsed/hover mode */
const SidebarSubHeader = ({item}) => (
    <li className="sidebar-subnav-header">{item.name}</li>
)


var Menu = MenuData.NIL;
class Sidebar extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collapse: {},
            role: 'NIL'
        }
        var u = this.props.sessionState.appUser;
        Menu = MenuData.NIL;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.sessionState.appUser) {
            const u = this.props.sessionState.appUser;
            this.setState({
                role: u.role
            })
            Menu = MenuData[u.role];
        }


        // pass navigator to access router api
        SidebarRun(this.navigator.bind(this));
        // prepare the flags to handle menu collapsed states
        this.buildCollapseList()
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.sessionState.appUser) {
            const u = nextProps.sessionState.appUser;
            this.setState ({
                role: u.role
            });
            Menu = MenuData[u.role];
        }
    }
    /** prepare initial state of collapse menus. Doesnt allow same route names */
    buildCollapseList = () => {
        let collapse = {};
        Menu
            .filter(({heading}) => !heading)
            .forEach(({name, path, submenu}) => {
                collapse[name] = this.routeActive(submenu ? submenu.map(({path})=>path) : path)
            })
        this.setState({collapse});
    }

    navigator(route) {
        this.props.history.push(route);
    }

    routeActive(paths) {
        paths = Array.isArray(paths) ? paths : [paths];
        if (paths.indexOf(this.props.location.pathname.replace('/','')) > -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    toggleItemCollapse(stateName) {
        for (let c in this.state.collapse) {
            if (this.state.collapse[c] === true && c !== stateName)
                this.setState({
                    collapse: {
                        [c]: false
                    }
                });
        }
        this.setState({
            collapse: {
                [stateName]: !this.state.collapse[stateName]
            }
        });
    }

    getSubRoutes = item => item.submenu.map(({path}) => path)

    /** map menu config to string to determine what elemetn to render */
    itemType = item => {
        if (item.heading) return 'heading';
        if (!item.submenu) return 'menu';
        if (item.submenu) return 'submenu';
    }

    render() {
        const r = this.state.role;
        const Menu = MenuData[r];

        return (
            <aside className='aside-container'>
                { /* START Sidebar (left) */ }
                <div className="aside-inner">
                    <nav data-sidebar-anyclick-close="" className="sidebar">
                        { /* START sidebar nav */ }
                        <ul className="sidebar-nav">
                            { /* START user info */ }
                            <li className="has-user-block">
                                <SidebarUserBlock/>
                            </li>
                            { /* END user info */ }

                            { /* Iterates over all sidebar items */ }
                            {
                                Menu.map((item, i) => {
                                    // heading
                                    if(this.itemType(item) === 'heading')
                                        return (
                                            <SidebarItemHeader item={item} key={i} />
                                        )
                                    else {
                                        if(this.itemType(item) === 'menu')
                                            return (
                                                <SidebarItem isActive={this.routeActive(item.path)} item={item} key={i} />
                                            )
                                        if(this.itemType(item) === 'submenu')
                                            return [
                                                <SidebarSubItem item={item} isOpen={this.state.collapse[item.name]} handler={ this.toggleItemCollapse.bind(this, item.name) } isActive={this.routeActive(this.getSubRoutes(item))} key={i}>
                                                    <SidebarSubHeader item={item} key={i}/>
                                                    {
                                                        item.submenu.map((subitem, i) =>
                                                            <SidebarItem key={i} item={subitem} isActive={this.routeActive(subitem.path)} />
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                </SidebarSubItem>
                                            ]
                                    }
                                    return null; // unrecognized item
                                })
                            }
                        </ul>
                        { /* END sidebar nav */ }
                    </nav>
                </div>
                { /* END Sidebar (left) */ }
            </aside>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    sessionState: state.sessionState
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

});



const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    translate('translations')
)(Sidebar);

//export default translate('translations')(withRouter(Sidebar));
```

finally, here is what it looks like rendering two components:

[image]

You can see the dashboard component (showing the user role) on top of the User List component that I just navigated away from.  Only the dashboard component should show.  Now if I enter the dashboard route directly in the address bar, it reloads the app and shows what I expect...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  My app.js was polluted in an experiment.  Reverted back and now it is fine.